# Pipes between parent and two children in C

Tags: c, pipe, exec, fork, parent-child

I am trying to write a C program that uses pipes to send information between the parent and two children. The goal of the program is to achieve something similar to merge sort, for strings. I read the number of strings and then the Strings. The strings get divided between the 2 children, recursively until each child has only one string. I have to redirect the stdin of the child to read from the stdout of the parent.

For some reason none of the children read more than the first string.
How could I solve this problem?

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int nrrows = 0;
    char * buffer = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    getline(&buffer, &n, stdin);
    char * endptr;
    nrrows = strtol(buffer, &endptr, 10);

    char rows[nrrows][MAX_LEN];
    int i = 0;
    n = 0;
    while(i < nrrows) {
        char * row = NULL;
        getline(&row, &n, stdin);   
        strcpy(rows[i], row);
        i++;
    }

    if(nrrows == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", rows[0]);
        return 0;   
    }

    int fdcp1[2];
    int fdcp2[2];
    if(pipe(fdcp1) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe unsuccessfull\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(pipe(fdcp2) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe unsuccessfull\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pid_t chpid1 = fork();
    if(chpid1 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork unsuccessfull\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else if(chpid1 == 0) {
        close(fdcp2[0]);
        close(fdcp2[1]);

        close(fdcp1[1]);
        dup2(fdcp1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        execlp("./forksort", "child1", NULL);
    }else {
        close(fdcp1[0]);
        dup2(fdcp1[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

        double half = (nrrows / 2);
        int h = half;
        char b[2];
        b[0] = '0' + h;
        b[1] = '\n';
        write(fdcp1[1], b, sizeof(b));

        for(i = 0; i < h; i ++) {
            rows[i][strlen(rows[i])] = '\0';
            write(fdcp1[1], rows[i], sizeof(rows[i]));
        }

        pid_t chpid2 = fork();
        if(chpid2 < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "fork unsuccessfull\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }else if(chpid2 == 0) {
            close(fdcp1[0]);
            close(fdcp1[1]);

            close(fdcp2[1]);
            dup2(fdcp2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            execlp("./forksort", "child2", NULL);
        }else {
            close(fdcp2[0]);
            dup2(fdcp2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            half = (nrrows / 2);
            h = half;
            char b[2];
            b[0] = '0' + (nrrows - h);
            b[1] = '\n';
            write(fdcp2[1], b, sizeof(b));

            for(i = h; i < nrrows; i ++) {
                rows[i][strlen(rows[i])] = '\0';
                write(fdcp2[1], rows[i], sizeof(rows[i]));
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't these lines `pid_t chpid2 = fork();
pid_t chpid1 = fork();` cause creation of additional child of the first child? chpid2 and chpid1 will be created by parent, but another chpid1 will be created by parent's chpid2.

Comment: Ok, I know that. But they child1 still can't read.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time and will to dive into code, but maybe the pipe is just closed before by the other child. Just fix the forking code and check if it is fixing the behavior.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I updated my code and fixed the problem causing additional children. Could you please take a look now, as the children still don't read properly?

Comment: Switching to low-level I/O with `write()` is not an especially good approach for what you're trying to do.  There are complications involved that you are not dealing with, and that you can avoid any need to deal with by using stream I/O.  Your current issue, for instance, is likely related to the fact that you are writing more data to your child processes than you think, in the form of a null byte after each newline plus subsequent garbage.  (And that's if you're *lucky*.)

Comment: @JohnBollinger At first I tried it using fprintf and getline but it still didn't work. In fact it actually seemend to be worse (as far as I remember , the second child wouldn't read anything at all. )

Comment: The problem is not `fprintf()` or the other stream I/O functions (such as `fputs()`).  They work for me in the code I gave you.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should stick to one I/O style.  If you are going to feed data to the children via `write()`, then they ought to read it via `read()`.  And as I said, that introduces additional complications that you need to worry about, such as that `read()` and `write()` do not necessarily read or write the exact number of bytes you ask them to do.

Comment: Also that `write()` doesn't know about strings and string terminators.  It just writes up to the number of bytes you say, from the location you say.

Comment: All that aside, what could be the problem? I did use fpritf() to no avail. Then I changed it to write(). I will change it back to fprintf(). But what could the problem be then?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that the parent does not close -- or at least flush -- the writing end of the pipes when it has done writing.  (If you are using stream I/O, then you should do that by `fclose()`ing the stream, not by `close()`ing the underlying FD.)

Comment: Assuming, of course, that you have corrected the problem I previously described with the parent modifying the FDs underlying the standard streams while actively using the standard streams.

Comment: Also, you may need to close the original pipe FDs after you `dup2()` them onto the standard FDs.  (Do use `close()` for that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bad news to modify a file descriptor that is associated with an open stream.  I would account it highly likely to cause you trouble, and there is, moreover, no need to do that here.  The parent should instead use `fdopen()` to open new streams on top of its ends of the pipes, and conduct I/O with its children via those instead of via the standard streams.  In addition to being safer, that leaves the process's original standard streams available for it to communicate with its parent process.

With that approach, you could even stream the strings to be sorted back and forth among the processes, instead of redundantly buffering blocks of them in each process's memory.  For instance, you might do something like this:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char * buffer = NULL;
    size_t buflen = 0;
    int nrrows;
    int fdpc1[2];
    int fdcp1[2];
    int fdpc2[2];
    int fdcp2[2];
    pid_t chpid1;
    pid_t chpid2;
    FILE *pipeout;
    FILE *pipein1;
    FILE *pipein2;
    int half;
    int i;

    fprintf(stderr, "%s!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n", argv[0]);

    getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin);
    fprintf(stderr, "number: %s from %s\n", buffer, argv[0]);
    nrrows = strtol(buffer, NULL, 10);

    if(nrrows <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "This is not a valid >0 number\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else if (nrrows == 1) {
        /* ... read and echo back the one row ... */
        getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", buffer);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    /* There are at least two rows to sort */

    if (pipe(fdcp1) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe unsuccessfull\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (pipe(fdpc1) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe unsuccessfull\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    chpid1 = fork();
    if (chpid1 == 0) {
        /* this is child process 1 */
        close(fdcp1[1]);
        close(fdpc1[0]);
        dup2(fdcp1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fdcp1[0]);
        dup2(fdpc1[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fdpc1[1]);
        execlp("./forksort", "child1", NULL);
    } else if (chpid1 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork unsuccessfull\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* this is the parent process */

    close(fdcp1[0]);
    close(fdpc1[1]);

    if (pipe(fdcp2) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe unsuccessfull\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (pipe(fdpc2) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe unsuccessfull\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    chpid2 = fork();
    if (chpid2 == 0) {
        /* this is child process 2 */
        close(fdcp1[1]);
        close(fdpc1[0]);
        close(fdcp2[1]);
        close(fdpc2[0]);
        dup2(fdcp2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fdcp2[0]);
        dup2(fdpc2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fdpc2[1]);
        execlp("./forksort", "child2", NULL);
    } else if (chpid2 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork unsuccessfull\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* this is the parent process */

    close(fdcp2[0]);
    close(fdpc2[1]);

    /* copy the first half of the lines from input to child 1 */

    pipeout = fdopen(fdcp1[1], "w");
    if (pipeout == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fdopen unsuccessful\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    half = nrrows / 2;
    fprintf(pipeout, "%d\n", half);
    for (i = 0; i < half; i += 1) {
        getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin);
        fprintf(stderr,"row[%d] from %s: %s", i, argv[0], buffer);
        fputs(buffer, pipeout);
    }
    fclose(pipeout);

    /* copy the second half of the lines from input to child 2 */

    pipeout = fdopen(fdcp2[1], "w");
    if (pipeout == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fdopen unsuccessful\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(pipeout, "%d\n", nrrows - half);
    for (; i < nrrows; i += 1) {
        getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin);
        fprintf(stderr,"row[%d] from %s: %s", i, argv[0], buffer);
        fputs(buffer, pipeout);
    }
    fclose(pipeout);

    /* now read and merge sorted lines from the children */

    pipein1 = fdopen(fdpc1[0], "r");
    pipein2 = fdopen(fdpc2[0], "r");
    if (pipein1 == NULL || pipein2 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fdopen unsuccessful\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* ... */

    fclose(pipein1);
    fclose(pipein2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And in my limited testing, that appears to exhibit all child processes successfully communicating.

Comment: I updated my code, and detailed my requirements a bit.

Comment: In case it's unclear: each parent opens new streams on top of its ends of the pipes to talk to its children; the children's ends of those pipes, on the other hand, are mapped to their standard streams.

Comment: Updated to demonstrate closing the pipe FDs after duping them onto the standard I/O FDs.  This is good general practice, though it didn't seem to be necessary for me in this case.